# POST to PHP file doesn't work in Fiddler

Tags: ajax, jquery, rest, post, fiddler

I have this very basic PHP file uploaded to `www.example.com` (not local):

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
echo $_POST['var1'];
?>
```

I composed a simple test in Fiddler as below

[image]

I got blank result, nothing back. It supposed to give me `test1234` in TextView

[image]

I tested with simple `$.ajax` call and it works in the browser. I also uploaded to another domain name to test cross domain call, it works too.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://www.example.com/test.php",
    data: {var1: "test1234"}
}).done(function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
});
```

However, if I swapped everything to GET (php, Fiddler), it works. **So why I can't get Fiddler to pass POST params?**

Comment: Keep in mind that when you're using POST, the sent content should be in the BODY (bottom box on the composer) not in the URL.

Comment: It works. Can you post as an Answer and I will approve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Even though there's already a very short answer in the comments, I just had the same problem and wanted to provide a slightly longer solution/explanation, because at first glance I didn't get the difference:

**Your problem is that PHP's `$_GET` and `$_POST` don't map to HTTP's `GET` and `POST`:**

- `$_GET` gets variables passed [via the URL parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)
- `$_POST` gets variables passed [via the body of the request message, when the content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

**...no matter whether the request was made via HTTP `GET` or `POST`!**

Your `$.ajax` test worked because you passed the value via the request body.
Your Fiddler test didn't work because you passed the value via URL parameter.

---

So there are two possible solutions for Fiddler:

1. Pass parameter via URL, get value in PHP via `$_GET['id']`:

   [image: GET]
2. Pass parameter via "Request Body", use one of the content types mentioned above, get value in PHP via `$_POST['id']`:

   [image: POST]